# HTML5 + JavaScript Silverlight/.NET runtime

Tags: javascript, .net, silverlight, html, clr

While MSIL is a [open Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) and there are runtimes written fot other OS than Windows ([Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/)) I was thinking about an implementation of the CLR in pure JavaScript.
It would be really nice to run a .NET App (maybe Silverlight only) directly in the browser, without any browser plugin.

With the introduction of HTML5's [typed arrays](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman%3atyped_arrays), the [`<canvas> element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/) and [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) there must be (in theory) a way to built a Silverlight/.NET runtime in pure JavaScript.
(This has been done for flash too: Project "[Gordon](https://github.com/tobeytailor/gordon/wiki/)")

But the question I asked was: Would that work today?

I took a look at the [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) source code, wich is really nothing simple. Would Javascript even been fast enough (today)? What about mobile devices?

**Would there be a way to write a CLR, which downloads a XAP file from the server (by using AJAX), opens that, runs it and draws the UI onto a canvas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Check out Fayde @ http://fayde.wsick.com.  The site is just being launched even though the project has been under development for almost a year now.